# Law of total covariance for products of random variables

Tags: sampling, conditional-probability, covariance

I have two sets of random variables.

$X_i \sim N( \theta, \sigma^2 )$, where $X_i$ are i.i.d.

$Z_j$ which are simply iid binary random variables with success probability $p$.

I want to find $\text{Cov}( X_i Z_j, X_i Z_k )$, $j \neq k$. I tried using the law of total covariance but not sure if my reasoning is valid:

\begin{align}
\text{Cov}( X_i Z_j, X_i Z_k ) & = \text{Cov}( \text{E}( X_i Z_j \mid Z ), \text{E}( X_i Z_k \mid Z ) ) +
\text{E}( \text{Cov}( X_i Z_j, X_i Z_k \mid Z ) ) \\
& = \theta^2 \text{Cov}( Z_j, Z_k ) + \sigma^2 \text{E}( Z_j Z_k ) \\
& = \sigma^2 p^2
\end{align}

I wasn't sure if it's okay to treat $Z_j$ and $Z_k$ as constants and pull them out in the step $\text{E}( \text{Cov}(X_i Z_j, X_i Z_k \mid Z ) )$, since we're conditioning on them.

Comment: Are the $X$s and $Z$s correlated?

Comment: No they can be assumed independent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct, but there is an easier way to do the problem with just the definition of Cov.

\begin{align*}
Cov(X_i Z_j,X_iZ_k) & = E(X_i^2Z_jZ_k) - E(X_iZ_j) E(X_iZ_k)\\
& = E(X_i^2)E(Z_j)E(Z_k) - E(X_i)^2E(Z_j)E(Z_k)\\
& = E(Z_j)E(Z_k) \left(E(X_i^2) - E(X_i)^2 \right)\\
& = p^2 \sigma^2.
\end{align*}